# Debugger steps deeper when trying to step out of C++11 std lib

Tags: c++, debugging, xcode4, c++11, llvm

I'm using (Apple) LLVM 4.1 within Xcode 4.5 (but I saw the same thing in an earlier beta).
I have it targeting C++11 and am using libc++ (the new, C++11 enabled, LLVM version of the std library).

In a debug build, if I try to step over code that calls into a std library function (e.g. a std::vector constructor) the debugger stops in the std lib implementation and if I try to step out it steps even deeper!
It can take several (sometimes 10 or more) step-outs before I get back to my own code (and I never wanted to step in in this first place).

There always seems to be a _LIBCPP_DEBUG macro in view, as well as _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY - but these seem to be everywhere so I'm not sure it's a correlation. It does seem plausible that it has something to do with the way inlining is working, though.

I've not been able to find any examples of anyone else with this problem - yet, for me, it has persisted across several betas - into the release - and through a complete reinstall of the OS.

Has anyone else even *seen* this? - but better still knows what's going on?

Comment: Haven't upgraded my XCode yet, but when debugging code that has been compiled in release mode, the debugger can go a bit wild at times. Are you seeing this in code compiled in debug mode?

Comment: Yes, sorry, meant to say it was a debug build. I've editing the question to reflect that.

Comment: Also I'm pretty sure I was seeing this in a beta of an earlier version - 4.2 or 4.3, maybe. At the time I suspected it was just a beta thing and would be sorted out by the release (no, I didn't submit a radar - I just GTFO cf. http://fixradarorgtfo.com).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

lldb in Xcode 4.5 doesn't handle stepping over inlined functions.  The libc++ standard library has many functions that are always inlined, even when built at -O0, which makes this a problem.  It looks like Jim Ingham worked on this about a month ago, e.g. see the first patch http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?view=rev&revision=163044 and several follow-on patches over the following week or two, but of course those aren't in a released version of lldb yet.  You can build and use a command line version of lldb from the public site, http://lldb.llvm.org/ (see in particular http://lldb.llvm.org/build.html ), the only tricky bit is to remember to follow the code signing instructions in lldb/docs/code-signing.txt.

Comment: Thanks (sorry - didn't see your reply before). It makes me feel better that its not just me. But frustrated that there is no workaround, currently, that doesn't involve using an "unofficial" lldb. Looks like it should resolve in time, though.

Comment: Almost Christmas and still has this problem (or has it again, either way, still dropping the ball over at Apple on this).

Comment: Xcode 4.5.x is still the currently released version, so yes, inlined code support is not yet available in a released Xcode.  Inlined stepping works correctly with current sources of the compiler and debugger -- there are still corner cases that step into a std function on occasion but those are down to the compiler's debug info.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this too, and not only with libc++, also with libstdc++ (the GNU C++ standard library, used by GCC and by clang in C++03-mode). I've always figured it's due to inlining, which I guess sometimes happens in debug builds too.

Comment: I have to admit I've never seen it in C++03 mode - which I use quite a lot