# xcode 4.5 debugger taking me into standard headers

Tags: xcode, debugging

I recently updated my Mac to Mountain Lion and also Xcode 4.5 . I do C/C++ programming often and i love Xcode. What i have noticed with Xcode 4.5 is while debugging it is taking me into the header files like for string and stand functions while i debug, for example

```
string tmp;
cin>>tmp;
for(int i=0;i<tmp.length();i++)
{
    //do something with the string
}
```

Now if i put a breakpoint at the for loop,everytime i pass by it, it takes me into the C++ string header and runs line by line code in it and then comes back to my code. This was not the case with Xcode 4.4. Is there anyway to disable this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has already been answered in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12651441/debugger-steps-deeper-when-trying-to-step-out-of-c11-std-lib%20%22another%20Stack%20Overflow%20post.). The short answer is that LLDB doesn't appear to skip inline functions yet.