# xcode 4.5 keeps stepping in std::string internal code

Tags: ios, xcode, string

I have a very annoying problem with XCode 4.5.1.

Each time my code is about to call some STL member functions (for example std::string::c_str()), XCode steps inside the call and I have to repeatedly step out to return back to get back to my source. This only happens with STL code, not my own functions.

How do I fix that annoying behaviour?

Thx.

Comment: dupe of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099916/stepping-through-the-code-is-stopping-on-stl-code-when-debugging-c-with-xcode?rq=1)?